# Ресурсы знаний, чтобы написать/создать Telegram-bot

Tags: telegram-bot, любой-язык

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ресурсы, которыми вы использовали для изучения, чтобы написать telegram-bot. При возможности покидайте ссылки на ресурсы.

Если я знаю Java, PHP, могу ли я написать `telegram-bot`? Если нет, то какие языки поддерживает `telegram-bot`?

P.S. может ли `telegram-bot` считывать информацию с интернет ресурса, копировать информацию и выставлять на канал?

*Пример: заходить на страницу в Вконтакте, копировать запись и прикрепленную картинку/видео и выставлять это на канале.*

Если мой вопрос некорректен/не нравится - помогите исправить или напишите ваше мнение в комментариях

Comment: набираете в гугле "telegram php" или "telegram java". первые же ссылки как раз о написании ботов на этих языках. А можете ли вы его написать или нет, нам то откуда знать

Comment: @Mike про "могу ли я" - я имею ввиду поддерживает telegram Java и PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Боты телеграма работают так:

1. Вы говорите телеграму что у вас есть сервер по такому-то адресу.
2. Когда человек пишет боту в телеграме, то он пересылает сообщение юзера по адресу из п.1 в виде JSON
3. Вы у себя на сервере как угодно и на каком угодно языке делаете что угодно с пришедшей от телеграма строкой.
4. Закончив серверные дела вы шлёте телеграму ответ в виде JSON
5. Телеграм пересылает ваше сообщение из п.4 юзеру из п2.

Т.е. ответы на вопросы таковы:

> Если я знаю Java, PHP, могу ли я написать telegram-bot

Если вы их знаете, то очень мало того чего вы не можете сделать.

> Если нет, то какие языки поддерживает telegram-bot?

Никакие. Надо просто обмениваться строками с их сервером. Для этого любой язык подойдёт.

> может ли telegram-bot считывать информацию с интернет ресурса, копировать информацию и выставлять на канал?

Т.к. сам бот это любой код на любом языке, то он может вообще всё.

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, ресурсы, которыми вы использовали для
>   изучения, чтобы написать telegram-bot. При возможности покидайте
>   ссылки на ресурсы.

Туториалов не кину, но читать лучше всего в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/). Там четко описано как обратиться к конкретному методу, что ему сообщить и что вы получите в ответ + список возможных ошибок и их исправлений.

> Если я знаю Java, PHP, могу ли я написать telegram-bot? Если нет, то
>   какие языки поддерживает telegram-bot?

Сервисы на подобие телеграмма (Vk, facebook WhatsApp...) работают с `HTTP` запросами. Им не важно какой язык вы будете использовать, чтобы сформировать запрос. Можете хоть просто в адресную строку браузера руками вписывать, ответ будет одинаковый.

> P.S. может ли telegram-bot считывать информацию с интернет ресурса,
>   копировать информацию и выставлять на канал?

Думаю телеграмм бот может все, что вы напишите. Само определение телеграмм бота описывает его использование для телеграмма. Парсинг информации с других сайтов, постинг в соцсети... это все делает программа(ваш бот). Телеграмм ботами их называют потому, что их основная цель телеграмм. Вы можете написать Телеграмм-Вк-Фейсбук-ВесьОстальнойИнтернет бот.

Более конкретно:

Для такого вы должны будете общаться с Вк апи [(документация)](https://vk.com/dev/methods), опять же `http` запросами, получать оттуда информацию и отправлять её http запросом на сервер телеграмм.

Answer (score 0):

Бот - это **обычная программа**, работающая с API. Соответственно, **как и любая другая программа**, бот может выполнять **абсолютно любые функции** у себя "*под капотом*", будь то считывание информации с интернет ресурса или что-либо другое.

Однако, взаимодействие с самим мессенджером (*Телеграм*) происходит строго в соответствии с правилами, определёнными [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). Для упрощения работы с API уже написано [множество библиотек-врапперов](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples), инкапсулирующих непосредственную работу с http-запросами и JSON-форматом в привычный синтаксис того или иного языка. Есть такие библиотеки (*причём их несколько для каждого языка*) и для [Java](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#java), и для [PHP](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#php). Как правило, в репозиториях этих проектов приведено множество примеров.